# How to restrict my groovy script to get only the build count for 24 hrs/1day and it fails if i run it when a job is under execution

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-api

I have the below groovy script designed to get me the total no of builds that have been triggered on each job, now i want to restrict it to just fetch the jobs that have been executed in duration of last 24 hrs also if i run this script on jenkins server when a build is running it return an exception as mentioned below

I have tried to perform the total+1 operation only if the job returned is not null. I am new to groovy if there is something i am doing incorrectly please do let me know. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
  def total =0 
  def total1=0
  def total2=0
  def daysBack=365

Hudson.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each {project ->
  def results = [:]
    results."$project.name" = [SUCCESS:0,UNSTABLE:0,FAILURE:0,ABORTED:0]
    def build = project.getLastBuild()  
  while (build){
      //println "$project.name;$build.id;$build.result"
      results."$project.name"."$build.result" = results."$project.name"."$build.result" +1
      build=build.getPreviousBuild()
     if(build != null){  
        total = total +1
      }
    }


  results.each{name,map->
    map.each{result,count->
      println "$name : $result = $count"
    }
  }

}
total2=total1+total
  println("The total no of jobs executed in last 24 hours are :$total2")
"Done"

Deploy_Servlet_Project : UNSTABLE = 0
Deploy_Servlet_Project : FAILURE = 5
Deploy_Servlet_Project : ABORTED = 0
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot execute null+1
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.plus(NullObject.java:135)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject$plus.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgmimpl.NumberNumberPlus$IntegerInteger.call(NumberNumberPlus.java:382)
    at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2040)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2025)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2066)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$163.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:6)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)
    at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:142)
    at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:114)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
    at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(RemotingDiagnostics.java:111)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins._doScript(Jenkins.java:4434)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doScript(Jenkins.java:4405)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:396)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:408)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:212)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:145)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:535)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:676)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:246)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.ResourceCacheControl.doFilter(ResourceCacheControl.java:134)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.auth.jwt.impl.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:61)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.plugins.greenballs.GreenBallFilter.doFilter(GreenBallFilter.java:59)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently build.getPreviousBuild() is not returning null, but a NullObject, thus your safety check is bypassed.